# How to use Distributed Entry Iterator feature with RemoteCache on Infinispan +7.1 version?

Tags: infinispan

I use keySet() api in production. But I know it's not recommended.

So I'd like to change it to new api over version 7.x
It's introduced on official blog.
http://blog.infinispan.org/2014/05/iterate-all-entries-in-cache.html

But I can't figure it out how to use it in Hotrod RemoteCache.

Anyone already tried successfully?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This was answered at https://developer.jboss.org/message/920029?et=watches.email.thread#920029

Radim Vansa said:

> Regrettably, this feature is not available yet over Hot Rod. Remote clients have certain lag after embedded-mode features. Map/Reduce and DistributedExecutors over HR are quite close on the roadmap, distributed entry retrievers should follow.

William Burns said:

> I also wanted to make sure you are aware that the keySet method is fine to use in the API as outlined [1].  The Cache Javadoc has some more specifics [2].  Basically the methods you should never use are the toArray methods on the collections returned from keySet, entrySet or values.  The other methods are done lazily.  Note this means the collection isn't a copy like before as well.
>
> Also to note if you do end up using any of the iterators from these bulk methods, you need to make sure to close them properly.
>
> However as Radim pointed out Hot Rod does not have this support yet (embedded only), but should be coming to a new version soon.
>
> [1] http://blog.infinispan.org/2014/11/why-doesnt-mapsize-return-size-of.html
>
> [2] https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/7.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/Cache.html#entrySet%28%29